# Change Image source inside a Button template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, button

I have a button in WPF application. I am presenting an image instead of a button. 
When my app comes up , all the controls are disabled , until a user logs in. I want my app to start with button that it's image is gray-->disabled . and when someone logged in , i want to change to color image.but i can't access the image in the button's template. can anyone help? thank you.

the code of my button -

```xml
<Button  Height="55" Background="CornflowerBlue" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" Name="Button_Cancel" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="55" Click="Button_Cancel_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel >
                    <Image Source="Images/myImage.png" Name="Image_Cancel"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.BitmapEffect" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="LightGray" Direction="300" ShadowDepth="5" >
                                </DropShadowBitmapEffect>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="0.970" ScaleY="0.970">
                                    </ScaleTransform>
                                    <!--<SkewTransform AngleY="2" CenterY="-100"/>-->
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook up the image with the `IsEnabled` property via trigger, then you probably don't need code behind access.

```xml
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Image_Normal.png" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Images/Image_Disabled" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this..

```xml
<StackPanel >
     <Image x:name="MyImage" Source="Images/myImage.png" Name="Image_Cancel"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and when you want to to access the image or modify it

```xml
<Setter Property = "Source" TargetName = "MyImage" value = "something"/>
```

Comment: thanks. But i want to access the image from code behind and i still can't do it...